# Hyperlinked image not clickable on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I have an image with a hyperlink that becomes unclickable when the css for smaller screens kicks in. I can't figure out why!

Here's the page: https://jupacharge.com/pages/become-a-reseller

This is the HTML of the page itself, the image/link in question is marked with **

```
<div class="reseller_container">
<div class="reseller_header">BECOME A RESELLER</div>
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1899/1203/files/jupa-reseller-background.png?12251079152443546141" />
<p>We're always on the lookout for <b>BUSINESSES OR INDIVIDUALS</b> who would like to <b>BUILD A RELATIONSHIP</b> with JUPA, whether that's <b>RESELLING</b> our charger or <b>ANYTHING ELSE</b>. If you feel this would be something for you then please <b>GET IN TOUCH</b> with us.</p>
**<a href="http://www.jupacharge.com/pages/contact"><img class="contact_button" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1899/1203/files/jupa-get-in-touch.png?15833297944705309626" /></a>**
<div class="reseller_text">We will aim to respond to your enquiry within 1 business day</div>
</div>
<img class="deal_icon" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1899/1203/files/jupa-deal.png?15833297944705309626" />
```

This is the CSS behind it, specifically the media query for < 600px seems to be the problem.

```
@media (min-width:600px) {

  .reseller_container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }

  .reseller_container p {
    position:absolute; 
    top: 17%;
    left: 10%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 3.5vmin;
    font-family: $bodyFontStack; 
    text-align:center;
    width:80%;
  }

  .reseller_text {
    position:absolute; 
    top: 95%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 2vmin;
    font-family: $bodyFontStack; 
    text-align:center;
  }

  .reseller_header {
    position:absolute; 
    top: 5%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #66BD00;
    font-size: 8vmin;
    font-family: ubuntu;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
  }

  .reseller_container a {
    color:#66BD00;
  }

  .contact_button {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 89%;
    left: 30%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 40%;
  }

  .deal_icon {
   display:none;
  }

}

@media (max-width:600px) {

  .reseller_container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }

  .reseller_container p {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 4vmin;
    font-family: $bodyFontStack; 
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
  }

  .reseller_text {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 2.5vmin;
    font-family: ubuntu; 
    text-align:center;
  }

  .reseller_header {
    position:absolute; 
    top: 4%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #66BD00;
    font-size: 12vmin;
    font-family: ubuntu;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 1em;
  }

  .reseller_container a {
    color:#66BD00;
  }

  .contact_button {
   display:block;
   margin:auto;
   width:80%;
   padding-bottom:5px;
  }

  .deal_icon {
   display:block;
   margin:auto;
   width:20%;
  }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the following rule.  Remove the `bottom: 0` and you should be fine.  It's an overflow issue.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .reseller_header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0; /* remove this */
    right: 0;
    color: #66BD00;
    font-size: 12vmin;
    font-family: ubuntu;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1em;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was a very easy fix. I would vote up can't it won't allow me.

Answer (score 1):

For for css that goes under 600px you need to set height of your header to 0. It is overlapping your content on lower resolution. But in the same place when it is more than 600px it is overlapping in dev tools but link is clickable.

Anyway, this is the code:

```
@media (max-width:600px) {

    ...

    .reseller_header {
        position:absolute; 
        height: 0;
        top: 4%;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        color: #66BD00;
        font-size: 12vmin;
        font-family: ubuntu;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align:center;
        line-height: 1em;
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried this as well and it works fine, although I went with the method below as it's 2 less lines of CSS.